# Pascal syntax error 85

Tags: pascal, freepascal, error-code, turbo-pascal

First off, I'm new to programming and I've just started learning pascal. I've encountered an error 85: ";" expected. I searched through the whole thing multiple times but I haven't been able to find the problem. Any suggestions?

Here's the code:

```
program test;
var
  a,b,c:real;
begin
  D:=sqr(b)-4*a*c;
  writeln('Enter a value for a');
  readln(a);
  writeln('Enter a value for b');
  readln(b);
  writeln('Enter a value for c');
  readln(c);
  if ( D<0 ) then
  begin
    writeln('There is no solution.');
  else
  if ( D>0 ) then
  begin
    x1:=(-b+sqrt(D))/2*a;
    x2:=(-b-sqrt(D))/2*a;
    writeln('x1 is:');
    writeln('x1:=',x1);
    writeln(x2 is:);
    writeln('x2:=',x2);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Didn't you get a line number for where the error occurred? Also, indent your code.

Comment: Nope. It only displayed an error 85. Nonetheless, thanks for your comment and suggestion for indenting my code. I'll try to do it more often in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three `begin` and only two `end` statements. Indent your code and you would notice your mistake. Variable D, X1, and X2 are also undefined. There are other syntax errors in your output, ie, missing tic marks `'`in one of your `writeln` statements near the end.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. I will try to indent my code in the future and also check it more carefully for any msitakes.

Comment: Yes, it is misleading. It was caused by the semicolon at the end of the `writeln('There is no solution.');` line of code. It would be better if the compiler would output `"Remove semicolon from statement prior to else clause"`. In Pascal, if there is an `else` then there must never be a semicolon on the previous statement.

Answer (score 0):

And you need a `end` before the else ..

```
program test;
var
  a,b,c:real;
begin
  D:=sqr(b)-4*a*c;
  writeln('Enter a value for a');
  readln(a);
  writeln('Enter a value for b');
  readln(b);
  writeln('Enter a value for c');
  readln(c);
  if ( D<0 ) then
  begin
    writeln('There is no solution.');
  end 
  else
  if ( D>0 ) then
  begin
    x1:=(-b+sqrt(D))/2*a;
    x2:=(-b-sqrt(D))/2*a;
    writeln('x1 is:');
    writeln('x1:=',x1);
    writeln(x2 is:);
    writeln('x2:=',x2);
  end;
end.
```